# How do I use the Bootstrap form select css with a Rails model?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use the Bootstrap css to style a "select" box in a form in a Ruby on Rails app.

On the Bootstrap site, they give this as an example:

```
<select class="form-control">
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
 <option>3</option>
 <option>4</option>
 <option>5</option>
</select>
```

However, I can not figure out how to combine this method with my ruby on rails code for the select area I want to do, so that it saves the selected option into the correct column (:ampm here) in my table. This is the code I have currently. It works, but does not have the bootstrap look I want:

```
 <%= f.label :am_or_pm %> 
 <div class="form-control">
 <%= f.select(:ampm, options_for_select([['AM', 1], ['PM', 2]])) %>
 </div>
```

I have tried a number of ways to integrate the Bootstrap example with my code, but nothing will work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: u need to add "form-control" class on select not on div.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

First of all, for bootstrap's `form-control` class to work, you must add it to `select` tag itself

Per [apidoc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select) of rails form select

```
select(object, method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

you can add html class as

```
<%= f.select(:ampm, options_for_select([['AM', 1], ['PM', 2]]), {}, {class: "form-control"}) %>
```

or simply

```
<%= f.select :ampm, [['AM', 1], ['PM', 2]], {}, {class: "form-control"}) %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate the help. Worked perfectly!

Comment: If you want the little dropdown arrow, use the class `"form-select"`

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```
<%= f.select :secretquestion, options_for_select([
  ["Select One", ""], 
  "Your nick name", 
  "your schoool name", 
  "your love name", 
  "your comapnay name", 
  "your favourite website"]), 
  {}, { class: "form form-group form-control" } %>
```