# How do you add a css class (Bootstrap) to a select field with a loop inside in Rails?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, loops

I have the following select field:

```
<%= f.select(:avaliador_id) do %>
  <% @usuarios_array.each do |u| %>
    <%= content_tag(:option, u.first, value: u.last) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

How do I add a css class (Bootstrap's form-control) to the select menu?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. The answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111088/how-do-i-use-the-bootstrap-form-select-css-with-a-rails-model/) shows how to do this without a each loop. But in my case there is a loop and I cannot get the css class to work.

Comment: Why do you need a loop? Why not just use `<%= f.select(:avaliador_id, options_for_select(@usuarios_array)), {}, {class: "form-control"}) %>`?

Comment: @mmichael You are right. I really do not need it. I cannot believe I didn't think this before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select
The method is as follows: 
select(object, method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
Since you're passing a block and the object argument is the f variable, the following should work:

```
<%= f.select(:avaliador_id, {}, {class: "form-control"}) do %>
  <% @usuarios_array.each do |u| %>
    <%= content_tag(:option, u.first, value: u.last) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

However, I'm not sure if that will account for the choices argument, so it may instead be:

```
<%= f.select(:avaliador_id, nil, {}, {class: "form-control"}) do %>
  <% @usuarios_array.each do |u| %>
    <%= content_tag(:option, u.first, value: u.last) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I think `<%= f.select(:avaliador_id, nil, {}, {class: "form-control"}) do %>` will work

Comment: @Eric N The second one worked for me, thanks. But as mmichael said, I didn't need the loop in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a loop, use:

```
<%= f.select(:avaliador_id, options_for_select(@usuarios_array)), {}, {class: "form-control"}) %>
```